# Symfony2 Validator Component on a string

Tags: php, symfony

I want to do simple validation on a string using symfony2 Validator Component. (This needs to be in symfony 2.0)

```
$responseEmail = 'somestring';

$validator = new Validator(
    new ClassMetadataFactory(new StaticMethodLoader()),
    new ConstraintValidatorFactory()
);

$constraint = new Assert\Collection(array(
    'responseEmail' => new Assert\Collection(array(
        new Assert\Email(),
        new Assert\NotNull(),
    )),
));

$violations = $validator->validateValue(array('responseEmail' => $responseEmail), $constraint);
```

This gives me an error:

```
Expected argument of type array or Traversable and ArrayAccess, string given
```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Variables don't match is this a typo: `$responseMail` and `$responseEmail`?

Comment: fixed thanks, but still problem is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment your telling the `$constraint` that responseEmail is an array.

Try this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
...
class ...
{
    public function validationAction()
    {
        $validator = Validation::createValidator();
        $responseEmail = 'somestring';
        $constraint = new Assert\Collection(array(
            'responseEmail' => array(new Assert\Email(), new Assert\NotNull()),
        ));

        $violations = $validator->validateValue(array('responseEmail' => $responseEmail), $constraint);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah you are right. Just a reminder for anyone who is still using 2.0 - for 2.0 use my code as the part of the answer is using 2.1